# Is it possible to send Http post request with content type multipart/form-data (files) and json object with data parameters alongside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, multipartform-data, body-parser

I want to allow users to upload documents. They can set title, expiration date and can pick number of files from their on end and click the upload button and send it all to the server.

I then insert a new document with the details they send plus handling the saving of the files they were attached.

Here is an example of a document inserted:

```
// documents collections: 
{
  title: "Some contract",
  expiration_date: DATE,
  files: [
    "uploads/1.jpg",
    "uploads/1.docx",
    "uploads/1.pdf"
  ]
}
```

I am able to allow the user to send and upload those files successfuly using formidable node.js module.

I am able to allow the user to send data parameters using body parser and then have access of them in the `req.body` object.

However I cannot have both of them on the same request.

What makes me think that I need to allow the upload in an individual request and then return it's files (paths) back to the client and then send another http post request with the json object parameters.

But that seems too complicated. But it also can be a good thing to let the user to first upload the file and meanwhile the files are uploaded, he can continue to fill the form.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send both types in the same request since one of them has header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and json requests have the header `Content-Type: application/json`. You could hack your way around that by using multipart form data, stringifying your json and adding it as a text field but I highly advice against doing that.
Multipart form data does support adding multiple files to a single key in the request form

Comment: Can you please show an example of "adding multiple files to a single key"?

Comment: just for the sack of not repeating code, you can have a look at the popular module "request" and the section about sending attachments https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms
Please tell me if you still have any problems